# How To Access Dynamically Created Buttons Click events Qt C++

Tags: c++, qt

I Created buttons dynamically for data from the database

```
QPushButton *btnComment = new QPushButton("Comment");
               btnComment->setProperty("id",qry.value(0).toString());
```

Is the button that i created dynamically
I set a connect

```
connect(btnComment, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &Planner::commentButton);
```

and created a function on slots

```
public slots:
    
    void commentButton();
```

How can I get the id value so I can execute a SQL query after the button click

I tested the function

```
void Planner::commentButton()
{
    
    QMessageBox inpass;
       inpass.setText("Comment");
       inpass.exec();
    return;
}
```

It works but after clicking OK the application closes

I get something like this in the console

```
QMainWindowLayout::addItem: Please use the public QMainWindow API instead
```

Any possible approach ?

Update

I was able to solve the lambda issue by declaring the passing variable as a global variable

```
connect(btnComment,  &QPushButton::clicked, this, [this]{ commentButton(taskID); });
```

Comment: what is `inpass.exec()` supposed to do? Why are you build a new message box in your slot, then setting its text, then doing `exec` and then just returning? that makes no sense.

Comment: It was just to test if my button click works

Comment: ok. But it's the reason you get your closing application. So, not a good test

Comment: Ok. What is the approach for my main requirement. I need to use the ID so can update the database

Comment: Why not just [`connect` to a lambda](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#connect-5) that has `btnComment` bound to it?

Comment: How can I connect to lambda. Can you please drop the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment you can `connect` to a lambda rather than directly to a non-static member.

Change the signature/definition of `Planner::commentButton` to...

```
void Planner::commentButton (QPushButton *button)
{
    
    /*
     * Use button accordingly.
     */
}
```

Then simply change your `connect` call to...

```
connect(btnComment, &QPushButton::clicked, this,
        [this, btnComment]
        {
            commentButton(btnComment);
        });
```

Now a pointer to the `QPushButton` that triggered the call will be passed to `Planner::commentButton`.

Comment: You don't need a lambda for that, `QObject` already has a [sender()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#sender) method.

Comment: @ixSci but that one has been up for breaking the isolation a thousand times, also it breaks guarantees if used across thread boundaries. So, personally, I'd avoid the `sender()` method if I can achieve the same with a lambda.

Comment: I went with an approach where the parameter passing is declared as a Global variable and the lambda issue was solved

Comment: But my application closes after the function is called. Any reasons for it i called the function using ```connect(btnComment,  &QPushButton::clicked, this, [this]{ commentButton(taskID); });```

Comment: @Planner If you're still having problems then you should probably open a new question.  Also (and at the risk of voicing a personal opinion), using a global variable for this is almost always the *wrong* thing to do.

Comment: @G.M. Thank you You were correct the global variable just get assigned the last one. Your Approach works perfectly and will help many. I marked it as Correct